# java mongo json schema validation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

I would like to know if mongock supports synthax such as:

```
 "allOf": [{ "$ref": "/schema/base" }]
```

when it build the validation during the collection creation or if you know a library that can be used to "merge" all the references in a unique big json schema that can be given as input to the Document used for the validation.

The code I'm using to validate a collection is:

```
    String jsonString = readJsonFile(fileName);

    Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);

    ValidationOptions validationOptions = new ValidationOptions();
    validationOptions.validator(doc);
    validationOptions.validationAction(ValidationAction.ERROR);
    validationOptions.validationLevel(ValidationLevel.STRICT);
    CreateCollectionOptions cco = new CreateCollectionOptions();
    cco.validationOptions(validationOptions);
```

As you can see for now I'm simply reading the json schema from the file and parse it with the Document object.

I would like to keep the json schema simpler as possible to be human readable and I have objects that extends others, so it would be easier to have separated json schema files to represent the super objects.

I'm using java 1.13 and spring boot 2.4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongock currently doesn't provide a schema validation mechanism. However, the team is considering to add as a patch after version 5 is released

Comment: Still no support for schema validation? Feels like the most needed feature of data migration tools

Comment: @user7551211 we still have some other priorities, we'll get there as soon as can. However, it would be great if you want to contribute. Mongock team is happy to provide some bounty for this ;)

If that's the case, contact us on development@mongock.io

Answer (score 1):

As this may be a helpful information on this topic - it's possible to add validation rules when creating the collection using Mongock. What works for me:

```
mongoTemplate.createCollection(FileInfo.class, CollectionOptions.empty()
        .validator(Validator.schema(MongoJsonSchema.builder()
                .required("fileStatus", "path")
                .build())));
```

Will make this two fields required.